# How can I execute a function defined in bash profile, from a launchD plist file?

Tags: macos, command-line, launchd, plist

I want to run a function defined in my .bash_profile file.

How do I execute this function from launchd?

Here is my plist file, 'backupIf' is my function.  In my launchd GUI editor it tells me 'no such file: backupIf' and when I set this up I don't get any results.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/usr/local/sbin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>atreeon.run_backup</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>backupIf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>1740</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't seem to read functions from my bash_profile.  Instead I added an alias in my bash_profile to point at a script and pointed my plist file at the same script.  I think this is a better solution anyway instead of having a massive bash_profile with many functions in it.

1. put my function in a bash script & save it to the file system (ensuring #!/bin/bash is at the top of the file)
2. write `alias backupIf=bash xyz/mybashscript` in my bash_profile file
3. in my plist file then point to my script `xyz/mybashscript`
4. ensure bash has read access to the folder in `xyz/mybashscript`

Comment: This is OK but I would make the xyz/mybashscript paths absolute one ie begin with / otherwise they depend on your current directory

Comment: You could also put all your bash functions into a separate file and source it both from `.bashrc` and from any script which needs to use some of these functions.